# Why does changing the fully qualified domain name in /etc/hosts not update the fully qualified domain name?

Tags: ip, ubuntu-18.04, hostname, domain-name, fqdn

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 in a VM. When I check the hostname using `hostname` or the fully qualified domain name using `hostname -f`, `hostname --fqdn` or `hostnamectl` I get the default `ubuntu` for each. I want to permanently update the hostname to `host` and the fully qualified domain name to `host.okd.dns`.

I have changed the file `/etc/hostname` to include only the name `host`. I have also changed the file `/etc/hosts` to appear as follows (excluding IPv6 hosts):

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       host.okd.dns
```

After saving and rebooting the VM, when I check `hostname` it returns `host` as expected, but when I check the FQDN using `hostname -f`, `hostname --fqdn` or `hostnamectl` it also returns `host` only without the `.okd.dns` appended to it as I would expect.

There seem to be several methods of updating the FQDN for Ubuntu 18.04 and I have tried most of them, including this method, which seems to be the most common. What do I need to do to get the changes to the FQDN to update and stick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, I needed to add `host` after `host.okd.dns` in the `/etc/hosts` file. I was sure I had tried this in the past, but perhaps there was some other error I had made somewhere and this wasn't reflected. Once doing this and after a reboot, `hostname -f` and `hostname --fqdn` both return `host.okd.dns` as expected.